# php header("Location:) used twice issue

Tags: php, http-headers

I am encountering an issue with this piece of code:

```
if (!empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password'])
     && $_POST['password'] == $_POST['confirm_password']
     && ( !filter_var ($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false ) ):
    //Enter the new user in the database
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (email, password) VALUE (:email, :password)";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':password', password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT));

    if( $stmt->execute() ):
        header("Location:succRegister.php");

    else : //this part of code is the problem
        header("Location:failRegister.php");//

    endif;
endif;

?>
```

I wish I knew why when the statement (`$stmt`) is not executed in regards to the conditions above, the link (`else`) doesn't work?
The first link does work.

Comment: How do you have the `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE` attribute set?

Comment: put `exit;` after each of the `header( ... )` call

Answer (score 0):

I think I see what might be the problem. If your first `if` condition is not met, *neither* of the headers will be reached. You can move the fail location outside the outer `if`, so that it will go there by default. Then on the inner `if`, exit immediately after sending the header.

```
if (!empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password'])
     && $_POST['password'] == $_POST['confirm_password']
     && ( !filter_var ($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false ) ):
    //Enter the new user in the database
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (email, password) VALUE (:email, :password)";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':password', password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT));

    if( $stmt->execute() ):
        header("Location: succRegister.php");   // only go here on success
        exit();
    endif;
endif;

// always go here if you haven't already gone somewhere else
header("Location: failRegister.php");
```

You can achieve the same thing with

```
if (!empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password'])
     && $_POST['password'] == $_POST['confirm_password']
     && ( !filter_var ($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false ) ) :
    //Enter the new user in the database
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (email, password) VALUE (:email, :password)";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':password', password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT));

    if ( $stmt->execute() ):
        header("Location: succRegister.php");   // only go here on success
    else:
        header("Location: failRegister.php");   // $stmt->execute failed
    endif;
else:
    header("Location: failRegister.php");       // $_POST validation failed
endif;
```

But if you are redirecting to the same page on either reason for failure, this is redundant.

Comment: Hello @gregory. I added another example to the answer to hopefully clarify the point I'm trying to make.